# Filenames with forward slash

Tags: box-api

I was wondering how you handled filenames with forward slashes in them? Currently(and I have no control or way to change it) our users can save files with slashes in them. When we test this out, the file on your system gets renamed to the whatever is after the last slash.

For example a file named Test10/09/2012.ppt would be renamed 2012.ppt.

What I would like to know is how do you guys handle incoming filename strings, and how we can encode them to have you accept a filenamed with slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forced renaming is actually not intended behavior. It's a bug that we're currently working on fixing. Box has a set of characters that are forbidden (\, /, ", :, <, >, |, *, ?, .), but we should alternatively be returning an error when you send such a character in the name of a file through the API.

We should have this fixed soon.

Comment: Ok thank you. We are going to just rename their file before we send it to Box and replace the illegal characters for them.

Comment: Do you have an exhaustive list of characters which not valid for filenames? I'm still using the original web API directly.  I can find this information in the documentation.

Comment: The list I provided above in my answer is the definitive list.